# Never allow my flutter app to deep sleep mode

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process

FYI: If some apps are not used for long time android system putting apps in sleep mode!

ques: is there a way to prevent it in flutter,cause my background process not working in deep sleep mode & I am not to get Notification message from FCM?

Comment: are you looking to keep the screen on if the app is left unattended for a long time?

Comment: no that is not the case

Comment: Are you perhaps looking to acquire a wake lock? Take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock

Answer (score 0):

try this ignoreBatteryOptimizations

```
var status = await permissionHandler.Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  var status = await permissionHandler.Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.request();
  if (status.isGranted) {
    debugPrint("Good, all your permission are granted, do some stuff");
  } else {
    debugPrint("Do stuff according to this permission was rejected");
  }
}
```

its also need Permission in AndroidManifest.xml like that:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```